# WooCommerce My Account Dashboard: Direct link to edit billing address

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

As I sell virtual products I don’t need the WooCommerce shipping address fields. I've already removed them from the checkout page and also want to remove them from the “My Account” page.

In the dashboard under the „Edit address“ tab the user should be directed directly to the page where he can edit the billing address. The page that shows the billing / shipping address and where the user has to click on "Edit address" is not longer needed.

Is there a way to achieve this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What code have you written already? Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of which of it is no longer needed?

Answer (score 1):

You can unset the `Address` endpoint and create a new one for `Billing`. For example, in your `functions.php` add the following code.

```
//1
function add_d_endpoint() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'billing', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_d_endpoint' );
//2  
function d_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'billing';
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'd_query_vars', 0 );
//3
function add_d_link_my_account( $items ) {
    $items[ 'billing' ] = 'Billing Address'; //The title of new endpoint
    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'add_d_link_my_account' );
//4
function d_content() {
    echo WC_Shortcode_My_Account::edit_address( 'billing' ); //The content of new endpoint
}
//5
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_billing_endpoint', 'd_content' );
// Note: add_action must follow 'woocommerce_account_{your-endpoint-slug}_endpoint' format

//6
/** Remove Address from My Account Menu **/
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'dsx_remove_my_account_dashboard' );
function dsx_remove_my_account_dashboard( $menu_links ) {
    unset( $menu_links[ 'edit-address' ] ); //remove the address from endpoint
    return $menu_links;
}
```

Then go to your `Dashboard` > `Settings` > `Permalinks`, then click the button `Save`, that should do it.

---

---

Alternatively, you can override the `my-address.php` located on `woocommerce/templates/myaccount`, just use `WC_Shortcode_My_Account::edit_address( 'billing' );`.

**Or** you can redirect into `Billing` when user(s) is trying to access the `Edit-Address` endpoint, try using the below code in your `functions.php`.

```
function redirect_to_billing( $wp ) {
    $current_url = home_url(add_query_arg(array(),$wp->request));
    $billing = home_url('/account/edit-address/billing');
    /** If user is accessing edit-address endpoint and it's not the billing address**/
    if(is_wc_endpoint_url('edit-address') && $current_url !== $billing){ 
        wp_redirect($billing);
        exit();
    }
    
}
add_action( 'parse_request', 'redirect_to_billing' , 10);
```

Comment: I tried the last solution. When I click on "Edit adress" the billing adress comes up and I can edit it. However, I cannot save the changes.

Comment: Does it happen in both methods?

Comment: Yes, same problem with the first method.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I'm not sure why it doesn't save the changes, perhaps there was a bug on it. I updated my posted answer, see the third method.